# Find a inverse function

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=x^3+px+q$ with $p\ge 0$, prove that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists, calculate $(f^{-1}(x))'$ and find $f^{-1}(x)$

I've already proved that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists: it follows from the facts that $f$ is strictly increasing(then injective) and that is a third degree polynomial, which implies it's range is $\mathbb{R}$ and so is surjective. Then is bijective and has inverse. About how to calculate the rest, I've got no idea. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your question is right? See wolframalpha.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{\frac{dx}{dy}}$ 
So $\int \frac1{3x^2+p}dx$ will be the answer. Now if the constant of integration troubles you then use $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ 
$$\int \frac1{3x^2+p}=\frac1{3\sqrt p}\arctan{\frac{3x}{\sqrt p}}+C$$
Now for the value of $C$, there would be some complicated function minus the integral.

Answer (score 0):

If $ y=x^3+p x+ q, $

then

$$ X = Y^3 + p Y + q $$

$$ \frac{dY} {dX} = \frac {1} {dx/dy} $$

EDIT1:

Comment: Your 2nd step is wrong. $Y\neq y$ same for $x$

Comment: Oh, I would take that part out, anyway you have given it right..